# Knockout PureComputed Invoking Subscribers when Recreated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, publish-subscribe, observable, knockout-3.0

I have a form with sets of data. When I click on a set (or row), it populates the form with that set of data.

For each set, I have a pureComputed object that will update the database whenever one of the inputs change.

This works fine except that the pureComputed invokes the update when I click on a different set. I expect this not to happen because I build the set of inputs with a constructor and so I essentially replace all of the observables and their respective pureComputed property.

For example:

```
var Form = function (data) {
    var $this = this;
    $this.value1 = ko.observable(data.value1);
    $this.value2 = ko.observable(data.value2);
    $this.model = ko.pureComputed(function () {
        return {
            value1: $this.value1(),
            value2: $this.value2(),
        };
    }).extend({ updateModel: url }); 
};

//Inside some module
var self = this;
self.viewmodel = {};

var load = function (url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url, //etc
    }).done(function (response) {
        self.viewmodel.form(new Form(response));
    });
};
load('www.myapi.com/1');

var onClick = function () {
    load('www.myapi.com/2');
};
```

Also, the update isn't invoked on page load. Why is it invoked when I click on a new row?

**EDIT**: UpdateModel code...

```
ko.extenders.updateModel = function (target, options) {
    var url = options;

    target.subscribe(function (model) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
        }).done(function (response) {
            /* not setting any observables */
        });
    };

    return target;
};
```

**EDIT 2**: The above is actually working in my code. I narrowed the culprit down to the knockout bindings for the dropdown.

Part of each Form is a dropdown. I use knockout's built-in bindings for the dropdown and I include a placeholder. If the dropdown's value is null or 0, then the value invokes the subcriptions. If it's greater than 0 then its fine.

Comment: Can you show what `updateModel` does?

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your code and created a working sample version here. It does not run the update function unless the values are changed. In other words, the "click" does not update anything.

```js
ko.extenders.updateModel = function (target, options) {
  var url = options;

  target.subscribe(function (foo) {
    console.log(url, foo);
  });

  return target;
};

var Form = function (data) {
  var $this = this;
  $this.value1 = ko.observable(data.value1);
  $this.value2 = ko.observable(data.value2);
  $this.model = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    return {
      value1: $this.value1(),
      value2: $this.value2(),
    };
  }).extend({ updateModel: data.url }); 
};

//Inside some module
var vm = {};
vm.viewmodel = {
  form: ko.observable()
};

var counter = 0;
var load = function (url) {
  url = url + (++counter);
  setTimeout(function () {
    vm.viewmodel.form(new Form({
      value1: "1"+counter,
      value2: "2"+counter,
      url: url
    }));
  }, 100);
};

load('www.myapi.com/');

vm.onClick = function () {
  load('www.myapi.com/');
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: viewmodel.form">
  <input data-bind="value: value1">
  <input data-bind="value: value2">
</div>
<button type="button" data-bind="click: onClick">click</button>
```

Comment: This is great! It's what I'm doing but I keep getting updates. My real solution uses kendo grid to populate a grid and clicking on the rows populates the form. I think I just need to comb through all of the code (again) and make sure I'm not doing anything that would invoke a subscription. :/

Comment: I discovered the problem. It is not related to this. It more so has to do with knockout bindings for options with a placeholder. Anywho, should I delete this question?

Comment: I figured it out. I was initializing the dropdown value to null instead of undefined and so the value was actually changing from null to undefined.